# Make the ion-select options selected while performing CRUD Operation in Edit Mode

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, angular2-directives

I am performing CRUD Operations with multiple fields. I have `[(ngModel)]` for all the fields.

> I am not interested to changed the name of the [(ngModel)] or assign any value in the `register.ts` or `edituser.ts` file while loading. Since I have made the form to save the values successfully in the register mode to the DB. I need to show the Inserted value in the Edit user Form and how can i perform that.

**Note:** I have several other fields namely text field, textarea, password in both the forms but somehow I have managed to save the data into DB during Registration Process and in Edit User Section also I have displayed the Values that has been Inserted in Edit Mode for all the other input types except the `ion-select`.

**Eg:** In the Register Form if the user has selected "Male" as the Option in the Edit Mode I need to stay with the user's Input right but the form shows again "Gender" instead of showing the selected value.

Below I have listed both of the forms that contain `ion-select` and my efforts what i have made.

**register.html**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Gender</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
     <ion-option value="Male">Male</ion-option>
     <ion-option value="Female">Female</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

**Edituser.html**

I have tried various options but this one alone worked. But this is not the one I am looking for. As of now `[(ngModel)]="editUser.gender"` is working and the value gets selected in the options tag but this is not i wanted. I need the model to be as follows `[(ngModel)]="gender"` but the value must be selected using any of the methods available.

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label floating>Gender</ion-label>
   <ion-select [(ngModel)]="editUser.gender" name="gender">
      <ion-option value="Male">Male</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="Female">Female</ion-option>
   </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

`editUser` contains the JSON data that comes from the DB.

Here the major drawback is that when I provide the modelname like this the value is not been fetched when the form is been submitted. So i need option to make the value selected without the change in the `[(ngModel)]`.

> My aim is to keep the Model as I have in the **register.html** form  [(ngModel)]="gender" for both the Register and as well as the Edit Form.

Comment: Why don't you go with a FormGroup? You could put the ion-select field (or entire form) inside FormGroup then remove ngModel and use `formControlName="gender"`. this will give you more control over the form

Answer (score 7):

I dont believe that there is a way to do what you are describing. However, there is a workaround to this.  The Ionic Select component will emit an ion-change event,refer to the [Output Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/#output-events) section in the API documentation. Here is the implementation.

```
 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender" (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)">
```

Answer (score 3):

on loading page, get `gender` from `editUser` object

```
 ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.gender = this.editUser.gender;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TypeScript component should look similiar to this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
// ...

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'Edituser.html'
})

export class YOURCOMPONENT {

  // ...

  constructor () {

    this.gender = this.editUser.gender;

  // ...
```